# App.exe.config not being replaced

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, app-config

I have an application that was shoddily created which resulted in some very sensitive information ending up being potentially very visible within the App.exe.config file after an install. I am presently banging my head against the wall in a thus far futile attempt to delete and replace the .config file via an application update, but all attempts have, as previously stated, proved futile.

My employer is laboring under what I believe to be the delusion that removing the lines in the config file is as simple as writing something into the program that looks at the .config file and deletes them, however 1: I do not think it is that simple and 2: That the file is not being updated with the more recent is indicative of a larger problem that needs to be resolved.

I have tried (in the setup and deployment project) setting the "Remove Previous Versions" to true, and I've incremented both the installer version number and the application version number forward, but neither have worked.

Why is the installed applications app.exe.config not being removed/replaced/updated?

Comment: do you want to remove that file from machines with already installed software? - like remote machines that you cant access manually?

Comment: I don't want to remove it. I want it updated. New installs are not updating the file, it just sits there. But yes, I would imagine if it were completely deleted from existence a new install would replace it, and if that is something that is not too difficult to do then I can deal with that.

Comment: Make sure that you are incrementing at the minimum the third section. i.e 1.2.X   The 4th section contains revision # and isn't enough to trigger a replacement.

Comment: Care to phrase that in the form of an answer so I can mark it? Thanks it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When incrementing your version number make sure you increment at least the third section which is the build number, the fourth section is the revision number which will not force a replacement of the older file.  See this MSDN link [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370859(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370859%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

The format is Major.Minor.Build.Revision

From link:

> Note that Windows Installer uses only the first three fields of the product version. If you include a fourth field in your product version, the installer ignores the fourth field.